# pandas - how to organised dataframe based on date and assign new values to column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe of a month excluding Saturday and Sunday, which was logged every 1 minute.

```
                            v1         v2  
2017-04-03 09:15:00     35.7       35.4  
2017-04-03 09:16:00     28.7       28.5
      ...               ...        ...
2017-04-03 16:29:00     81.7       81.5
2017-04-03 16:30:00     82.7       82.6
      ...               ...        ...
2017-04-04 09:15:00     24.3       24.2  
2017-04-04 09:16:00     25.6       25.5
      ...               ...        ...
2017-04-04 16:29:00     67.0       67.2
2017-04-04 16:30:00     70.2       70.6
      ...               ...        ...
2017-04-28 09:15:00     31.7       31.4  
2017-04-28 09:16:00     31.5       31.0
      ...               ...        ...
2017-04-28 16:29:00     33.2       33.5
2017-04-28 16:30:00     33.0       30.7
```

I have resample dataframe to get 1st and last value from each day.

```
res = df.groupby(df.index.date).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[[0, -1]])
res.index = res.index.droplevel(0)
print(res)
                      v1    v2
2017-04-03 09:15:00  35.7  35.4
2017-04-03 16:30:00  82.7  82.6
2017-04-04 09:15:00  24.3  24.2
2017-04-04 16:30:00  70.2  70.6
   ...                ..    ..
2017-04-28 09:15:00  31.7  31.4
2017-04-28 16:30:00  33.0  30.7
```

Now i want to have the data-frame organised as date with v1 of minimum timestamp and v2 of max timestamp of specific date.

Desired output:

```
              v1    v2
2017-04-03  35.7  82.6
2017-04-04  24.3  70.6
   ...       ..    ..
2017-04-28  31.7  30.7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can groupby on index and use [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with a custom function.

```
df1 = res.groupby(res.index.date).agg({'v1': lambda x: x[min(x.index)], 'v2':lambda x: x[max(x.index)]})

print (df1)

             v1      v2
2017-04-03  35.7    82.6
2017-04-04  24.3    70.6
2017-04-28  31.7    33.7
```

An alternative to resample dataframe to get 1st and last value from each day.

```
res=df.reset_index().groupby(df.index.date).agg(['first','last']).stack().set_index('index')

Out[123]:

                      v1     v2
index       
2017-04-03 09:15:00  35.7   35.4
2017-04-03 16:30:00  82.7   82.6
2017-04-04 09:15:00  24.3   24.2
2017-04-04 16:30:00  70.2   70.6
2017-04-28 09:15:00  31.7   31.4
2017-04-28 16:30:00  33.0   33.7
```

Comment: hey, you having max and min value, my question is to have v1 always for lowest time and v2 always for maximum time for any given date

Comment: @stockade I didn't notice the constraint at first. Sorry. I've updated the code.

Comment: i am getting as per the desired output. your answer is correct. i am waiting for alternative and eventually will accept your answer

Comment: quick query about the alternative which you have provided to get 1st and last day from each day is faster or slower than mine way??

Comment: @stockade I think `apply` would be faster. It's just an alternative. :) Your's is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame()
df_result['v1'] = res.groupby(res.index)['v1'].min()
df_result['v2'] = res.groupby(res.index)['v2'].max()
```

Comment: getting wrong output with date time repeating and value of v1 v2 also

Comment: can u show head of your results and describe what's wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

You can `reset_index` and then `GroupBy` + `apply` with a custom function:

```
def first_second(x):
    return pd.Series({'v1': x['v1'].iat[0], 'v2': x['v2'].iat[-1]})

res2 = res.reset_index()
res2 = res2.groupby(res2['index'].dt.date).apply(first_second)

print(res2)

              v1    v2
index                 
2017-04-03  35.7  82.6
2017-04-04  24.3  70.6
2017-04-28  31.7  33.7
```

Comment: hey sorry to mention that's not the output required.you having max and min value, my question is to have v1 always for lowest time and v2 always for maximum time for any given date

Comment: @stockade, See update. My data is different (taken from your previous question), but the logic should be fine.

Comment: i understand the logic though accepted the answer of abhi with one liner. let me know your thoughts on that

Comment: @stockade, My thoughts are it's better to have an explicit function then wrap everything in `lambda` statements so that it fits in one line.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very interesting fonction in pandas to work with the datetime index.
It is the resampling fonction. 
In your Case try this :

```
def first_last(entry):
   return entry['v1'][0],entry['v2'][1]

yourdataframe.resample('D').apply(first_last)
```

the 'D' stands for Daily resampling.

result :

```
Dates                 
2017-04-03  35.7  82.6
2017-04-04  24.3  70.6
```