# Select the last value in time after multiple groupings

Tags: pandas

I want to group ‘name’ first, then press ‘day’ to aggregate and select the last value of each ‘name’ every day.

I got some ideas from here：[pandas - how to organised dataframe based on date and assign new values to column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52914017/10446425)

I tried this, but I can't succeed. Is there any good way?

```
df = df.groupby(df['name']).resample('D',on='Timestamp').apply(['last'])
```

eg:

```
import pandas as pd

N = 9
rng = pd.date_range('2011-01-01', periods=N, freq='15S')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': rng, 'name': ['A','A', 'B','B','B','B','C','C','C'],
                  'value': [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 3],'Temp': range(N)}) 
[out]:
    Timestamp           name    value   Temp
0   2011-01-01 00:00:00   A     1       0
1   2011-01-01 00:00:15   A     2       1
2   2011-01-01 00:00:30   B     3       2
3   2011-01-01 00:00:45   B     2       3
4   2011-01-01 00:01:00   B     3       4
5   2011-01-01 00:01:15   B     1       5
6   2011-01-01 00:01:30   C     3       6
7   2011-01-01 00:01:45   C     4       7
8   2011-01-01 00:02:00   C     3       8
```

I want to get these:

```
[out]:
           Timestamp    name    value   Temp
1   2011-01-01 00:00:15   A     2       1
5   2011-01-01 00:01:15   B     1       5
8   2011-01-01 00:02:00   C     3       8
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

```
df.groupby('name').tail(1)
Out[25]: 
   Temp           Timestamp name  value
1     1 2011-01-01 00:00:15    A      2
5     5 2011-01-01 00:01:15    B      1
8     8 2011-01-01 00:02:00    C      3
```

Or

```
df.drop_duplicates('name',keep='last')
Out[26]: 
   Temp           Timestamp name  value
1     1 2011-01-01 00:00:15    A      2
5     5 2011-01-01 00:01:15    B      1
8     8 2011-01-01 00:02:00    C      3
```

Comment: My data set is not just a day's worth of data, it spans at least a month or more,
I think this answer is not suitable for this.

Comment: @罗文浩 `df.groupby([df.Timestamp.dt.date,df['name']]).tail(1)`

Comment: I like this answer, it is perfect and easy to understand.

Comment: Sorry for being off topic here - but why did you delete your last answer with this `df[df.filter(like='col_id'`-thing? It was perfect except `any`...

Comment: @SpghttCd I feel like that is lack of explanation and can not make the edit at this moment

Comment: You made a correct answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/56194585/8300135 and deleted it later.

Answer (score 1):

If need last values per days and per column `name`, use [`GroupBy.tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html) with [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='D', key='Timestamp'), 'name']).tail(1)
print (df1)
            Timestamp name  value  Temp
1 2011-01-01 00:00:15    A      2     1
5 2011-01-01 00:01:15    B      1     5
8 2011-01-01 00:02:00    C      3     8
```

Or convert values of `Timestamp` to dates by [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
df2 = df.groupby([df['Timestamp'].dt.date, 'name']).tail(1)
print (df2)
            Timestamp name  value  Temp
1 2011-01-01 00:00:15    A      2     1
5 2011-01-01 00:01:15    B      1     5
8 2011-01-01 00:02:00    C      3     8
```

There are also alternatives with [`Series.dt.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html):

```
df2 = df.groupby([df['Timestamp'].dt.normalize(), 'name']).tail(1)
```

Or [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html):

```
df2 = df.groupby([df['Timestamp'].dt.floor('D'), 'name']).tail(1)
```